# How to evaluate an input cell automatically after evaluating the previous one

Tags: notebooks, cells

Is there any way to automatically evaluate an input cell after evaluating the previous one without the need to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?

Comment: Out of curiosity - is there a reason why you wouldn't want to put them into the same cell?

Comment: @Jonie Because I want the next cell be evaluated only if certain conditions are met. I also want to separate the outputs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to acheive this is:

```
a = 1 + 2
If[a == 3, SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]];
SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]];
```

---

Other way is by adding `CellTag` to our "conditional" cell. Use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on that cell or use menu: Cell > Cell Tags > Add/Remove... to add tag, here I used `"only if"`.

And then:

```
a = 1 + 2;
If[a == 3,
   NotebookLocate["only if"];
   SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]]
  ]
```

This seems to be more bulletproof.

Comment: Thanks. Your solutions are exactly what I needed.

Comment: @M6299 You are welcome :) I'm glad you find it useful.