# Skipping sections of a notebook automatically

Tags: evaluation

I have a notebook which allows to set some parameters at the start, and then does computations depending on these parameters. 
It is a long notebook and for readability it is broken up into sections and subsections etc.

Now for some values of the parameters, certain sections of calculations are not necessary, so I want to skip these whole sections, without having to put them in one evaluation cell. Is this possible?

I tried putting this piece of code in the beginning of the section I want to skip:

```
 If[p>3,Goto[nextsection]];
```

And in the following section,

```
 Label[nextsection];
```

This is the effect I want, except that it doesn't work, because for Goto the label needs to be in the same input cell.

When I run it manually I can of course just skip it, or comment it out, but I'm running this notebook automatically (using the code in my own answer to my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95785/evaluate-notebook-from-other-notebook)) so I want to automate this skipping as well.

Comment: Not an answer,  but in the long run you might consider consolidating your code into `Function`s or `Module`s or even packages to facilitate repeated evaluation. This should also help eliminate errors caused by wrong evaluation order etc..

Comment: If you mean you've put the code in different cells, then you can use functions like `NotebookFind` and `SelectionEvaluate`.  But it seems less trouble to do as Yves suggests.

Comment: Maybe this can be marked as a duplicate, what do you think? [How to evaluate an input cell automatically after evaluating the previous one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29994/5478). The question is not the same but the answer is similar.

Comment: This is indeed close to an answer, but not quite yet. I want to be able to evaluate everything (ctrl+A and shift enter or have another notebook do this) and skip a subsection depending on some condition. Your answer to the other question doesn't seem to achieve this. If I use `NotebookLocate["next"]; SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]];` in the beginning of the section that is to be skipped, and i mark some cell in the next section with `next`, the effect is something else. Everything is evaluated, and after this is done, the cells marked next are evaluated again

Comment: @Jansen What about putting a prolog cell as a first cell in those conditional sections, if the condition is not met it could drop evaluation from parent group and move to next. Is that ok?

Comment: It seems there should be a way to use cell tags, tag cells as "debug" for example, then have a keyboard equivalent to control-a that would "select all cells except with the debug tag"

Answer (score 4):

I put conditional code in a *delayed* `Block`, and added a toggler which defines wither that block is to be run on "Evaluate Notebook" or not:

[image]

(the point of first two lines here is to make the notebook yield exactly same results upon multiple runs of "Evaluate Notebook")

If you'd rather use global variables in your conditional `Block` use:

```
testX := Block[{},
   x
   ];
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking with the same question.  Best I've found... With the section selected you can simply use menu pull-down "Edit Un/Comment selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>)".  All inputs in the section will be commented out at the same time preventing their execution during the next global <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> select and process.